# Angular: where should transitions among states be?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

Here's a design issue:

I am making a web application with Angularjs, and I am trying to use the $stateProvider to model the routing of the sections within the app.
Imagine I have two states, A and B, each one with its template and controller:

```
.state('A', {
  url: "/A",
  templateUrl: 'templates/A.html',
  controller: 'ACtrl'
})

.state('B', {
  url: "/B",
  templateUrl: 'templates/B.html',
  controller: 'BCtrl'
})
```

Now suppose that from A, on a certain condition specified within A controller, I need to go to state B, what I would normally do is to call $state.go('B'); within the A controller:

```
.controller('ACtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.gotonext = function(){ $state.go('B'); };
})
```

Now, in my opinion, the next state after A should be specified where I define the routing, and not within the controller of A, something like this:

```
.state('A', {
  url: "/A",
  templateUrl: 'templates/A.html',
  controller: 'ACtrl',
  nextState: 'B' //<-- this line is not angular
})

.controller('ACtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.gotonext = function(){ nextState(); };
})
```

But I have found no way for doing something like this. Of course, there may be more than one "nextState", and these are contextual to the controller, but still, I would see the transition decoupled from the the actual landing state.

So here's the question:

**what is the best place where to specify the transition to the next state?**

Comment: so you are saying `B` should be default next state for `A`. if anyone trigger '$state.go()'. am i correct ?

Comment: in this case yes, it's a default next state, but in a general case, it really depends on what happens inside the controller of A.
I have update the example above with what the controller should look like, maybe this clarifies the question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility I have come up with is this one:

```
.state('A', {
  url: "/A",
  templateUrl: 'templates/A.html',
  controller: 'ACtrl',
  resolve: {
  transitions: function($state){
    return{
      nextState: function(){
        $state.go('B');
      }
    };
  }
 }
})

.controller('ACtrl', function($scope, transitions) {
  $scope.gotonext = function(){ transitions.nextState() };
})
```

I kinda like it because it leaves the transitions specified in the routing and is also generic so that you can specify all the transitions you like contextually to your state (e.g. nextState, backState, whateverState).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service to do so. it possible to pass custom data with `ui router` configuration so you can use that configuration to define default states as you wanted.

See the below code.

```js
// Global Strings Method to capitalize first letter of string
String.prototype.capitalizeFirstLetter = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  var btnsTemplate = '<button ng-click="gotoPrevious()">previous</button>' +
    '<button ng-click="gotoNext()">Next</button>';

  $stateProvider.state('A', {
    url: '/a',
    template: '<div> state A ' + btnsTemplate + '</div>',
    controller: 'aController',
    defautStates: {
      next: 'B',  // Will register $scope.gotoNext() method;
      previous: 'C' // Will register $scope.gotoPrevious() method;
    }
  }).state('B', {
    url: '/b',
    controller: 'bController',
    template: '<div> state B ' + btnsTemplate + '</div>',
    defautStates: {
      next: 'C',
      previous: 'A'
    }
  }).state('C', {
    url: '/c',
    controller: 'cController',
    template: '<div> state C ' + btnsTemplate + '</div>',
    defautStates: {
      next: 'A',
      previous: 'B'
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/a');

}).service('defaultRoutesMethods', function() {
  this.register = function(scope, state) {
    // Getting default states for current state.
    var defautStates = state && state.current && state.current.defautStates;
    if (scope && defautStates) {
      Object.keys(defautStates).forEach(function(key) {
        // generating mathod name using key values of default states object
        var methodName = 'goto' + key.capitalizeFirstLetter();
        // Adding method goto Methods on current scope.
        scope[methodName] = function() {
          state.go(defautStates[key]);
        }
      });
    }
  };
}).controller('aController', function($scope, $state, defaultRoutesMethods) {
  defaultRoutesMethods.register($scope, $state);
}).controller('bController', function($scope, $state, defaultRoutesMethods) {
  defaultRoutesMethods.register($scope, $state);
}).controller('cController', function($scope, $state, defaultRoutesMethods) {
  defaultRoutesMethods.register($scope, $state);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have used a slightly different version from yours, instead of having a service calling the state change I have created an object passed in "resolve", something like:

resolve: {
      transitions: function($state){
        return{
          loggedin: function(){
            $state.go('main.home');
          }
        };
      }
    }